# C# Return generic type without type parameter at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, return

Is it possible to return an object of type

```
 IModel< T >
```

without knowing the type parameter?

the objects are stored in a dictionary, with Type as the key and an object with `IModel`  (base interface to `IModel<T>`) implemented as a value.
The interface `IModel<T>` inherits from `IModel`, but to do the full action I need an object of `IModel<T>`. `T` needs to have the interface `IFactoryItem`.

but first the code:

```
    public IModel<T> GetModel<T>() where T : IFactoryItem
    {
         Type tmpType  = typeof(T);
         if (!_allModelsByType.ContainsKey(tmpType))
                return null;

         return (IModel<T>)_allModelsByType[tmpType];
    }
```

i thought of a solution like

public IModel GetModel(Type t) and a wrapper to cast it to the right type.

I hope that i am not totally wrong.
this is my first question.

Comment: Your method looks perfectly fine, presuming that the values in the dictionary line up with the type key.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to return an instance of `IModel<T>` but you don't know what `T` is at compile time, only that it is always derived from `IFactoryItem` then:

If you don't use `T` in a method input, and `T` is a class you can use covariance:

```
public interface IModel<out T> where T : class
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class Model<T> : IModel<T> where T : class
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var foo = new Model<string>()
        {
            Value = "hello world",
        };

        IModel<object> boo = foo;

        Console.WriteLine(boo.Value);
    }
}
```

That way you can pass around `IModel<IFactoryItem>` rather than `IModel<T>`

If you need value types though, or you can't use covariance then ideally you'd have (as you suggest) a second non-generic interface `IModel` that exposes any values as `object`

```
public interface IModel
{
    object Value { get; }
}

public class Model<T> : IModel, IModel<T> 
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    object IModel.Value => Value;
}
```

If your question is how to make an instance of `Model<T>` when you only know the type at run-time then its:

```
 var someType = typeof (SomeFactoryItem);
 var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (Model<>).MakeGenericType(someType));
```

you will still need to either return `IModel` or, if you can use covarience, `IModel<IFactoryItem>`

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to return an object of type `IModel<T>` without knowing the type parameter?

Technically no, but I think this was actually asked with a slight misunderstanding. The type of `T` **is** know, it is just generic -- in fact it is so well known that it is even constrained. Note the `where T : IFactoryItem`, this indicates that anything that attempts to execute either the `AddModel` or `GetModel` functions must be something that implements the `IFactoryItem` interface. If you trying writing something that calls either methods and passes into it anything other than an implementation of the `IFactoryItem` interface, it won't even compile.

Please consider the code below, the variable namely `fetch` is actually the same object as the variable `model` that was added!

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test();
        var model = new Model();
        test.AddModel(model);
        var fetch = test.GetModel<FactoryItem>();

        Console.WriteLine(fetch == model 
                              ? "It does in fact work..." 
                              : "Uh, that was supposed to work?");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _allModelsByType;

        public Test()
        {
            _allModelsByType = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        }

        public void AddModel<T>(IModel<T> model) where T : IFactoryItem
        {
            _allModelsByType.Add(typeof(T), model);
        }

        public IModel<T> GetModel<T>() where T : IFactoryItem
        {
            var tmpType = typeof(T);
            return _allModelsByType.ContainsKey(tmpType)
                ? _allModelsByType[tmpType] as IModel<T>
                : null;
        }
    }
}

internal class FactoryItem : IFactoryItem { }

internal class Model : IModel<FactoryItem>
{
    public FactoryItem Value { get; set; }
}

internal interface IFactoryItem { }

internal interface IModel<T> where T : IFactoryItem
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Running this program will output "It does in fact work..."

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="750" src="https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/J26ETn" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```